# How to make WCF service not deserialize message and just send it to the next service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, serialization, azure-web-roles

My system looks like this:

[image]

I need to send messages from `Management portal` to `WCF Service 1` to control the web application (clear cache, etc.).

The thing here is that messages have to pass through `WCF Service 2`. I cannot update `WCF Service 2` as often as the other two components (`Management portal` and `WCF Service`), so I have to make some kind of universal method in `WCF Service 2` which will just resend the message to the `WCF Service 1` without taking care about it.

How to make `WCF Service 2` act just as a proxy between `Management portal` and `WCF Service 1`?

(Note: I cannot call service 1 directly because Service 2 takes care about encryption, logging, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas depending on what other requirements you may have

1. Use a WCF [Router service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx) as this will simply pass your message along.  Its primary usage is for content based routing (on headers or even message content).  You can implement any custom code in behaviors/extensions.  Routers are nice because you can do most of it through configuration.
2. Change the contract of WCF Service 2 to accept a [Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675.aspx).  This prevents it from serializing and deserializing into .Net objects and essentially takes any request and forwards it on.

   ```
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IService2
   {
   //pass message to Service1
   [OperationContract]
   void MyMethod(Message m);
   }
   ```
3. Extend ClientMessageFormatter and DispatchMessageFormatter to override the default serialization implementation.  This is only if you want to change the *way* it is being serialized/deserialized or whether to be serialized/deserialized at all. This is probably not what you are looking for - but I thought I'd mention it anyway because your question mentioned you wanted a hook into where in WCF you can change this behavior.  See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183867.aspx) for details.